# Sort array by name with sort()

Tags: javascript

I am trying to sort an array by names in alphabetic order, with numbers it works, but with names doesn't. Why?

```js
var arr = [{
    name: 'Thomas',
    age: 19
  },
  {
    name: 'Noé',
    age: 17
  },
  {
    name: 'Andrey',
    age: 27
  },
  {
    name: 'Luc',
    age: 20
  }
]

const res = arr.sort((e1, e2) => e1.name - e2.name)

console.log(res)
```

Comment: `e1.name - e2.name` are you trying to subtract two strings? What do you except it to return?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings may not be subtracted, but you can compare them using [localeCompare](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare)

```
const res = arr.sort((e1, e2) =>
  e1.name.toLowerCase().localeCompare(e2.name.toLowerCase())
);
```